# How to change button id by pressing it?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, button

Imagine 2 different buttons and a picture. When you press one button, the image changes to another image. If you press the other button, it changes to different picture. And so on. It's like an interactive game.

I want the button to change id also, so you don't have to make a new activity each time, just keep going thru the pictures on the single activity. I only found 1 answer to this question and it advised against changing the id...

How do I change the id or is there a better solution for this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Register OnClickListener for each Button which changes the according Picture to a Picture you want to have. You can in Addition to that use a counter for each Button which determines which picuture should be shown.

```
val image_1 : ImageView
    val image_2 : ImageView
    val button_1 : Button
    val button_2 : Button
    var counter_1 = 0
    var counter_2 = 1
    button_1.setOnClickListener {
        when(counter_1){
            0-> image_1.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.1_1)
            1-> image_1.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.1_2)

        }
        counter_1++
    }
    button_2.setOnClickListener {
        when(counter_2){
            0-> image_1.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.2_1)
            1-> image_1.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.2_2)
        }
        counter_2++
    }
```

Comment: Can't declare those variables. Should I use = instead of : ?

Comment: This is just an example how it could look. The : are only there to show which class these variables are. You have to assign image_1,image_2,button_1,button_2 to the appropriate objects and you should give them proper names. You could for example do: val image_2 = R.id.image_2